# How to correctly represent a bone system?

Tags: 3d, animation, vector, linear-algebra

I'm currently representing my bone system as follows, in pseudocode:

```
root = {}
root.rot = v3(0,0,0)
root.pos = v3(0,0,0)

function create_child(parent,rot,length):
    child_bone = {}
    child_bone.rot = parent.rot + rot
    child_bone.pos = parent.pos + v3(0,0,bone.length).rotate(child_bone.rot)
```

This works for most situations, but sometimes I get weird occasions where rotating a parent bone makes the child bones rotate wildly. What is the proper mathematical representation of a bone system?

Comment: from the fact that you use a vec3 for your rotation i´m assuming that you´re using euler angles to represent rotations, you can´t just add them together to get the combined rotation. I would recommend to either use matrices or quaternions to concenate multiple rotations. Also check if your values are in correct space (relative to armature or to parent for example), that´s another common pitfall in skeletal animation

Comment: I don't get the last thing you said, and how exactly do I combine multiple rotations with quaternions? Just add them together?

Comment: Could you please describe what you are doing here? Is this for creating the bindpose? and are you coding an editor where you actually have to define bone positions and rotations or do you just want to render a given armature with a given animation?

Comment: @LuisW it is a simple editor in Three.js I made to help me getting a doll in the stance I want so I can draw my characters over it on photoshop. It helps a lot getting the positions correct. http://o7.no/15vcR25 I am not good with the mouse so it is the only way I found to animate a character using the keyboard...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Heres basically the idea of how to find a bones location:

You start in the bones local space, where the root is on the origin and the tip has a distance equal to the bone lenght along one of the axis from it, you use the z-axis as far as i can tell from your code, i used x in my images, i will refer to it as z-axis from now on since you use it that way(image1).

To go to the parents local space you have to do a rotation followed by translation. the rotation is the bone´s rotation relative to it´s parent, now the tip of the parent bone (green bone in image) is at the origin, we have to do the translation along the z-axis for the lenght of the parent bone to get to the local space of the green bone where the root is in the origin. (image 3)

We repeat these steps to get to local space of the red bone (image 4 & 5)

The last rotation is to get from the red bones local space to the armatures local space.(image 6) Note how all rotations are rotationg around diffrent pivot-points(allways the origin of the current system, but since you do translations in between they change), which is one of the problems in the code you posted.

You might have to apply another set of transformations to get to world-space if neccesary, if your armatures local space is not translated nor rotated relative to world space these steps aren´t required.

In my opinion there are 2 good ways of applying these transformations, one is by using matrices, the other by using quaternions.

> The 4 points p0, p1, p2 and p3 are the 4 points you see in image 6,
>   they are in order:   red root, green root, blue root, blue tip.
>
> len0 is red´s lenght, len1 is green´s lenght and len2 is blue´s
>   lenght.
>
> Rotations used are 30 for red (r0, q0), -30 for green (r1, q1) and 60 for blue (r2, q2). All relative to parent.
>
> Matrices have Column-vectors and post-multiplied because of that, so the transformations are applied from right to left.
>
> **Matrices:**
>
> ```
> //rotate creates a rotation matrix represented by an angle and an axis
> //translate creates a translation matrix along the specified vector
>
> mat4 r0 = rotate(30,vec3(1,0,0)) * translate(vec3(0,0,len0));
> mat4 r1 = rotate(-30,vec3(1,0,0)) * translate(vec3(0,0,len1)); 
> mat4 r2 = rotate(60,vec3(1,0,0)) * translate(vec3(0,0,len2)); 
>
>
> p0 = glm::vec4(0,0,0,1);
> p1 = r0 * p0;
> p2 = r0 * r1 * p0;
> p3 = r0 * r1 * r2 * p0;
> ```
>
> **Quaternions:**
>
> ```
> //angleAxis creates a Quaternion based on the angle and an axis    
>
> quat q0 = angleAxis(30,vec3(1,0,0));
> quat q1 = angleAxis(-30,vec3(1,0,0));
> quat q2 = angleAxis(60,vec3(1,0,0));
>
> p0 = vec3(0,0,0);
> p1 = q0 * vec3(0,0,len0);
> p2 = q0 * ( (q1 * vec3(0,0,len1) ) + vec3(0,0,len0) );
> p3 = q0 * (q1 * ( (q2 * vec3(0,0,len2) ) + vec3(0,0,len1) ) + vec3(0,0,len0) );
> ```

The code is basically applying all the transformations as described in the beginning. THe matrices are basically doing the translation and rotation for a single bone in one step, whereas the quaternions can only store rotation and you have to translate them in an extra step.

You can calculate the positions you need as described here. You can´t calculate a rotation the way you do it in your sample, since there is simly no rotation existing. The problem is that all the diffrent rotations applied are rotation around diffrent pivot-points and need to have translations in between. You can either store the rotation relative to the parent the way i did or you can use Matrices which can store translations and rotations in the same matrix to do something like this, then you won´t need the position anymore.

Hope this helps, feel free to ask questions.

Comment: I'd recommend a slightly less insane colour scheme for the figures. They're illegible for someone slightly colour blind like me.

Comment: @LarsViklund Oh sorry for that, i allways use Cornflower Blue as clear color so i didn´t really think about it, would black as background color help?